# Audit Logging for AWS QuickSight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-quicksight, amazon-cloudtrail

Newbie to AWS quicksight. Have a requirement to track Non-API Events for QuickSight . My requirement is to track events around the QuickSight Dashboards events and see which of the dashboards are having maximum hits .

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/logging-non-api.html

I'm not sure if I should configure it in CloudTrail or CloudWatch or both .  If possible please guide me with the steps .

For example , PowerBI has an inbuilt funtionality to track usage metrics for dashboards .

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-usage-metrics

Thanks .

Comment: This was possible . The CloudWatch logs for all quicksights report just needed to be pushed into an Athena Table by the administrator .

Comment: Rajesh, could you please explain how you were able to get CloudWatch logs enabled for Quicksight? It doesn't look like it's possible!

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/incident-response-logging-and-monitoring.html